# how to set selected value from list in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Modify search</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">For <span>Select</span><span style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">▼</span></a>

        <ul> <span><a href="#">Girlfriend</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Boyfriend</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Husband</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Wife</a></span> 
            <span class="cl"></span> <span><a href="#">Mother</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Father</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Daughter</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Son</a></span> 
                <span class="cl"></span> <span><a href="#">Friend (M)</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Friend (F)</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Colleague (M)</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Colleague (F)</a></span> 
                    <span class="cl"></span> <span><a href="#">Nephew</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Niece</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Aunt</a></span>  <span><a href="#">Uncle</a></span> 
                        <span class="cl"></span>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What i am trying to do is whenever i select any value it must be highlighted and it should be shown in the filter.[image]

For example if i select girlfriend the For : select should look like For : girlfriend

Comment: why you need :girlfriend like selectors?

Comment: Are you looking for automatic behaviour?  Or something with JavaScript?  Automatic behaviour is impossible - with JavaScript it's a fairly straightforward "onclick" handler that changes some classes/content.

Comment: you can write like this  $("a").click(function() { alert("look like for : "+$(this).text());});

Comment: What i want is when some one selects any of the following girlfriend, Mother, Father....etc . Then the text in front of For should change and the selected value should be displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess that the 'Select' text has the `id` 'select_id';

```
$('ul span').click(function(){

$("#select_id").html($(this).html);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){

  var clicked_link = $(this).text() // will get the text 
  $(this).attr('some_attr') // will get the value of an attribute in the clicked a tag

alert(clicked_link);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add an id to span `<span id="this">Select</span>`

then `getElementByI("this").innerHTML =` set to something you want

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute `getval` to span where you want to display selected item.

```
<span id="getval" style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">&#x25BC;</span>
```

**JQuery**

Get the text of `anchor` and then set it to where you want to display.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul span a").click(function(){
      $("#getval").text($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you can assign **ID** to the elements...

for example:

```
<a href="#">For <span id="select">Select</span>...
```

and also to the second `ul`:

```
<ul id="list">...
```

then you need something like that:

```
$('#list a').on('click', function() {
   var text = $(this).text(); //this take the text of the clicked text.
   $('#select').empty().text(text); //this assign the value.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
$(function(){
 $("a").click(function() {
    alert("look like for : "+$(this).text());// OR show this value in any particular DIV
    $(".displayDiv").text("look like for : "+$(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: but it is preferred if you add certain class to your <a> tag and change the selector accordingly.

Comment: Can it be possible to replace the text in front of For to something that is selected by the user.

Comment: yeah it is possible, let me know what you want to do exactly, right now if user have selected girlfriend, it should display girlfriend in front of For, is it doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You should have only `li` inside a `ul` and not spans. Others are [not permitted.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)

However, the answer you are perhaps looking for is :

```
$('ul li ul span').click(function(){

     $('ul li span').eq(2).text($(this).text());

}
```

And all this surely begs for the use of a class or id.